# What is causing (gnome-shell:3120): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, syslog

```
chris@localhost:/var/log$ lsb_release -crid
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

chris@localhost:/var/log$ apt-cache policy gnome-shell
gnome-shell:
Installed: 3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1
Candidate: 3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1
Version table:
*** 3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1 500
500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages


chris@localhost:/var/log$ apt-cache policy gdm3
Installed: 3.20.1-1ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1
Candidate: 3.20.1-1ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1
Version table:
*** 3.20.1-1ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1 500
500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

The complete error that is being written thousands of times to my syslog is

```
Dec 29 07:53:07 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3120]: (gnome-shell:3120): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta:  assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
Dec 29 07:53:07 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3120]: (gnome-shell:3120): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Dec 29 07:53:07 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3120]: (gnome-shell:3120): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Dec 29 07:53:07 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3120]: (gnome-shell:3120): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
Dec 29 07:53:07 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3120]: (gnome-shell:3120): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Dec 29 07:53:07 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3120]: (gnome-shell:3120): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Dec 29 07:53:07 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3120]: (gnome-shell:3120): Clutter-CRITICAL **: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
```

Because of this my syslog from yesterday at 7:35am until today at 7:35am when it's rotated is - 238121171 Dec 29 07:35 syslog.1 in fact it's so large for some reason it wasn't compressed. Today's syslog so far is 40027866 Dec 29 16:57 syslog and I imagine by tomorrow morning it will be close to the same size as yesterdays.

So, question is what's causing this and how can I troubleshoot and fix it?

Comment: I saw a post saying this comes from a bad gnome-shell extension `Taskbar`  with a recommendation to uninstall the extension. Source: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=124447